# Open source Google Sheets alternative for storing data for people who don't know how to work with databases

Tags: database, self-hosted, spreadsheet

My coworkers use Google Sheets for saving orders data with different parameters like order number, date of creation, status, expected date to finish production for this order and so on. There are some formulas as well as alerts using cells format like days expired. Now sheet is huge - around 15k rows and they work with on that page all together and it become laggy and breaks often.

I found there are alternatives that we can deploy on own server like Baserow or NocoDB but also found they are not truly open source and send data to third party servers. So is there something we can deploy on own server? It should be easy for people to edit and search data and have possibilities for automation (like auto calculated columns with different data and/or alerts).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NocoDB](https://nocodb.com/) and [Baserow](https://baserow.io/) both appear to have "open-core" models, meaning they are working to build proprietary [enterprise](https://docs.nocodb.com/FAQs#do-we-plan-to-have-an-enterprise-edition) products on top of their open-source products. Perhaps this open-core model is what you're looking to avoid. If it's only the telemetry you want to avoid, then I would imagine you could disable it. For example NocoDB [allows](https://docs.nocodb.com/setup-and-usages/usage-information/#opt-out) you to set `NC_DISABLE_TELE=true` to disable telemetry.

Here are some other products you might want to check out...

Fully open-source:

- [Mathesar](https://mathesar.org/) - Does not have telemetry in the product, but does have some in the [live demo](https://demo.mathesar.org). Does not yet support formulas, but [will eventually](https://mathesar.org/roadmap.html).
- [Baastronaut](https://github.com/baastronaut/baastronaut) - Still quite early. Not sure about the telemetry.
- [undb](https://github.com/undb-xyz/undb)

Open open-core products:

- [Grist](https://www.getgrist.com/)
- [Directus](https://directus.io/)
- [Rowy](https://www.rowy.io/)
- [APITable](https://apitable.com/)

*(Disclosure: I'm an engineer on the Mathesar core team.)*

Comment: Thank you so much! Checked all those variants and now I think to suggest my boss to setup NocoDB to play with it since it have all features including our language so it'll be easier for employees.
Mathesar looks promising as well in future, will check its development news, wish you all luck with this project!